# Python ssl client can't connect to socketserver with ssl

Tags: ssl, python-3.7

I am trying to create a server in python using socketserver and ssl.
It needs to work on TLS version 1.2 only.
I am trying to connect a client to it just to see that it works.
I know the server works without ssl, so it is the problem.

I do not know why i am getting this error. Even if I remove all changes to the context, they still won't connect.

```
class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):
    """My server."""
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        """Create a new server.
        If bind_and_activate is True, calls server_bind and server_activate."""
        super().__init__(server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=False)
        context = ssl.SSLContext()
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
        context.set_ciphers("ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES256-GCM-SHA384")
        context.set_ecdh_curve("secp256k1")
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.socket = context.wrap_socket(self.socket, server_side=True)
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        if bind_and_activate:
            self.server_bind()
            self.server_activate()
```

client:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
context.set_ciphers("ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:AES256-GCM-SHA384")
context.set_ecdh_curve("secp256k1")
sock = socket.socket()
sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False)
sock.connect(("localhost", 32571))    # port server is running on.
print("Connected")
```

Error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1056)
```

I just want to create a connection between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured any certificates for the server. While there are ciphers which don't require certificates (like PSK ciphers) the ciphers you have chosen use authentication with RSA certificates. Since there are none configured essentially no usable ciphers are there and the handshake will fail. Note that setting verify_mode to CERT_NONE will not help against this (and is usually a bad idea anyway) since this only means that a certificate will not be validated by the client and not that a certificate is not needed as part of the handshake.

Comment: Thank you! While I figured it out already, this answer is correct for anyone looking at this in the future.