# OpenADR2.0 VEN security testing with Test harness

Tags: python

I and my team are trying to build a VEN PULL implementation. We are using OpenLEADR-python library to build it. We are testing our implementation against the OpenADR 2.0 certification test harness, which we bought from QualityLogic. We are almost done with the implementation. But now facing problems with the security tests. While building both VTN and VEN with OpenLEADR, we could use the certificate and private-key generated with OpenSSL. But we are stuck with the security tests (G1_xxxx_TH_VTN_1) in the test-harness.

We believe we have to use certificate file, private-key file and passphrase. From where should we collect those files? Are those already given inside the test-harness? Or do we have to collect it from QualityLogic or any other source such as https://kyrio.com/openadr/ ? And how should we configure the OpenLEADR VEN and the Ubuntu environment to support the security tests both with test-harness and the certification?

Answer (score 2):

OpenADR 2.0a Certification Package_1.1.2 zip contains x509_Certs_v1_0_4.zip archive with some keys.

OpenLEADR documentation describes how to use custom keys:
https://openleadr.org/docs/message_signing.html

> You can sign your outgoing messages using a public-private key pair in
> PEM format. This allows the receiving party to verify that the
> messages are actually coming from you.
>
> If you want your client to automatically sign your outgoing messages,
> use the following configuration:
>
> ```
> async def main():
> client = OpenADRClient(ven_name='MyVEN',
>                        vtn_url='https://localhost:8080/',
>                        cert='/path/to/cert.pem',
>                        key='/path/to/key.pem',
>                        passphrase='my-key-password')
> ```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your comment. We have the OpenADR test-harness v1_1_6 and it has included some keys in the "src/certs/security/SHA256" directory in the test-harness codebase. There are a bunch of ROOT keys, intermediate keys, end keys, certs, keystores, truststores from both Kyrio and Eonti. But we are not sure which one to use. Let's say we want to use cert and key from Kyrio. But even from Kyrio, there are a number of keys. Which one to use? Also where can I find the "passphrase" for these keys?

Comment: Just to add one thing. Every request I am sending, I am seeing below error message in the python console -

Could not connect to server with URL https://127.0.0.1:8080/OpenADR2/Simple/2.0b:
ClientConnectorSSLError: Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:8080 ssl:default [Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:801)]

Comment: Here https://www.openadr.org/build-a-product it says you can "Download the test plan, sample payloads and certification documents from the members area (members only)". I understand you are using QualityLogic test tool, but maybe you have to use those keys from OpenADR site. If you download "OpenADR 2.0a Certification Package 1.1.2.zip" you will find word document there "OpenADR 2.0a x509 Certificates v1.0.4.docx" which explains how to load keys in eclipse, and also mentions password is "password".

Comment: In this document they also mention specific IP address to use so maybe that could help with the other error as well.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560334/python-ssl-client-cant-connect-to-socketserver-with-ssl